# KendoUpload - Change chunksize during upload or at runtime

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Upload for the chunk upload.

```
//On Initialization
 $("#folders").kendoUpload({
                    async: {
                        saveUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/ChunkSave",
                        removeUrl: baseAddrs + "/" + "DragAndDrop/remove",
                        chunkSize: 100000000, //~ 95MB
                        autoUpload: true,
                        concurrent: true

                    },
                    upload: onUpload,
                    directory: true,
                    directoryDrop: true,
                    complete: onComplete,
                    success: onFileSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
```

I want to change the chunksize value on upload as below but it is not happening: How i can change this value :

```
 function onUpload(e) { 
                    //File Count                   
                    var fileCount = this.wrapper.find(".k-file").length;
                    e.sender._module.metaData[e.files[0].uid].EntityID=entityID;
                    e.sender._module.metaData[e.files[0].uid].EntityType=docSrcType;
                    e.sender._module.metaData[e.files[0].uid].SelectedFolder=selectedFolder;
                    e.sender._module.metaData[e.files[0].uid].Key = entityID; 
                    e.sender._module.metaData[e.files[0].uid].uploadedFileCount = fileCount;
                    if (bChunkUploadFlag) 
                        e.sender.options.async.chunkSize = 10530000; // ~10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the properties of a widget by using the [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/methods/setoptions) method.

> Allows changing the widget configuration after initialization. Depending on the widget, some properties may not be changed, and the method's implementation varies for each widget.

```
var upload = $("#folders").data("kendoUpload");
console.log(upload.options.async.chunkSize);

upload.setOptions({
    async: {
        chunkSize: 10530000
    }
});

console.log(upload.options.async.chunkSize);
```

However, there are some things to consider when using `setOptions` as detailed in the documentation:

> In some cases, the setOptions method can recreate and rebind the widget instance. Calling setOptions in an event handler or the respective widget is not recommended and can cause an endless loop or a JavaScript error.

I haven't had any successful uploads when calling `setOptions` in the `onUpload` event ([dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AyuVAfOx)).

Using `setOptions` outside of the event has worked though ([dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ONuDadoR)).

I believe this answers you're question on how to change the value. Getting the value changed at the moment you want it to and the uploader still work, may take some rethinking.

Comment: This does not work, i am trying to upload a folder - https://dojo.telerik.com/ONuDadoR/4